# Insert into Hive with Dynamic columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr

I receive files where the columns are dynamic.
File1 can be

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7
```

File2 can be

```
column1 column2 column9 column10    column11    column12    column13
```

File3 can be

```
column1 column2 column3 column10    column11
```

How can i modify the hive table as the column i'll be receiving with the file.

Answer (score 1):

It would be really messy, but without any explicit delimiter, the best you could do would be define a RegexSerDe and capture every possible column.

Your missing columns would basically be an optional capture group `()?`

Your other option would be to get Spark to infer the schema and missing columns based on a header row, if you have one

As soon as you get a text table over the raw data, you should convert it a proper columnar data format.

Answer (score -1):

Hive expects the structure to be fixed, in-line with any RDBMs.

One option is you may want to include the full set of columns expected in all the files (if known upfront obviously) and only populate the columns for which the data is received and leave the others empty?